# Powershell update named element in object

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to automate the creation of user accounts via powershell. One part of it is to establish an e-mail address for the new users. We spread the mailboxes (more or less) evenly over 3 databases: Default01, Default02 and Default03.

To determine the database with the least amount of accounts I calculate the current statistics.

```
      function Get-MDBMailboxCount ([string]$DN) {
            $Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
            $Searcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://$(([system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain]::GetCurrentDomain()).Name)")
            $Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(homeMDB=$DN))"
            $Searcher.PageSize = 10000
            $Searcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
            $results = $Searcher.FindAll()
            $returnValue = $results.Count

            #dispose of the search and results properly to avoid a memory leak
            $Searcher.Dispose()
            $results.Dispose()

            return $returnValue

       }
$Databases = (Get-MailboxDatabase)  Where {$_.Name -like 'Default*'} | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Count";Expression={Get-MDBMailboxCount -DN $_.DistinguishedName}} | Sort-Object count


}
```

This returns an object $databases with the columns **Name** and **Count**. I then extract the DB with the lowest count.

```
$DB = $Databases |Sort-Object Count |Select-Object -First 1
```

So far so good :) But since my script will be able to create many accounts at once I want to update the counters every time a user is created in the $databases object. (I don't want to run the function again since it can take a few seconds to process). I am able to update the object like this:

```
($databases | Where {$_.Name -eq $($DB.Name)}).Count = $NewCount
```

But I'm wondering if there's an easier way to update elements in Powershell Objects. Something like

```
$Databases["Default01"].Count = $NewCount
```

Is something like that possible? Or is there no other/better way to update elements in an object?

Credit for the Get-MDBMailboxCount function goes to 
[link](http://blog.powershell.no/2010/11/21/retrieve-number-of-mailboxes-per-database-in-exchange-server-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a reference to the current DB object, then simply update its `Count` property directly.  The syntax is `$DB.Count = <new value>` or `$DB.Count += <amount to add>`

```
$databases = <do expensive get operation, get initial counts>

foreach($newUser in $userList)
{
   $DB = $databases | Sort-Object Count | Select-Object -First 1
   < go add users to the particular $DB, keep track of how many new users >
   $DB.Count += $numNewUsers   # or $DB.Count = $totalUserCount, whatever you like
}
```

`$DB` is a reference pointing to the same underlying object as is in the `$databases` array.  So when you set `$DB.Count`, it is also updating the proper element in `$databases`, and the next time the array is sorted, it will use the new count.

Comment: I know that you can do that for the current object. I just want to know if you can do it for any given element in the object based upon keyname eg $databases["default02"].count = 99

Maybe my example code isn't very good (it was just part of the script I'm currently working on). I mean this more in general: can you reference an element in an object by the column-name.

Comment: No, not in general.  Objects do not have "columns," they have "properties."  A single object might have a handful of properties, and you get or set them with the syntax `obj.Property`.  A *collection* of objects is simply that, a collection.  If you want to get or set a property on an element in the collection, you need to isolate that element first.  This is done either by indexing (e.g. get the 4th element: `$array[3]`) or querying (get the element with `Name = 'Joe'`: `$array |?{$_.Name -eq 'Joe'}`.

Comment: Certain specialized collection types, like HashTables, support indexing using some other object type.  This is very useful and fairly common, but you shouldn't assume every collection allows you to do something like this.  In powershell, cmdlets almost always returns simple streams of objects, which can only be queried or indexed by number.